# Why do I get "Incompatible Types" error using Kotlin "is" opeator

Tags: kotlin, typing

I have been experimenting with obtaining the type of a variable in Kotlin, and I find that can do this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var num1: Short = 1
    var num2 = 100000
    var num3 = 1000000000000
    var num4 = 3.14
    val numList: List<Any> = listOf(num1, num2, num3, num4)

    for(num in numList) {
        if (num is Short) {
            println("Short: $num")
        } else if (num is Int) {
            println("Int: $num")
        } else if (num is Long) {
            println("Long: $num")
        } else {
            println("$num not in listed types")
        }
    }
}

Output:
Short: 1
Int: 100000
Long: 1000000000000
3.14 not in listed types
```

... But I cannot do this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var num2 = 100000
    if (num2 is Long) {
        println("Long: $num2")
    } else {
            println("$num2 not in listed types")
        }
}


Output: 
    Kotlin: Incompatible types: Long and Int
```

Why?  What is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the elements in the `numList` have the compile time type `Any`:

```
val numList: List<Any> = listOf(num1, num2, num3, num4)
                  ^^^
```

In other words, `num` here is of type `Any`:

```
for(num in numList) {
    ^^^
```

Checking whether `num` actually stores a `Long` is allowed, because the compiler  *only* knows that its type is `Any`. It *could* actually store a `Long` at runtime.

On the other hand, when you declare and initialise `num2`, its type is inferred to be `Int`, because `100000` is an `Int` literal. The compiler knows that `num2` can *never* store a `Long` at runtime because its type is `Int`.

If you use the `Long` literal `100000L`, then your code would compile, and you will get a warning saying that `num2 is Long` is always true.

Answer (score 2):

In the second case the compiler knows that the check can't succeed, because it knows `num2` is `Int`, so it can't be `Long`. In the first case it does not know what is the type of `num` (it is `Any`), because `numList` contains objects of various types, so the check is allowed.

In other words, it makes sense to check whether some animal is a dog. However, it does not make sense to check if some cat is a dog.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the compiler understands in the second version that `num2` can only be an `Int` and thus the error.

In the first version, you are testing `num` which may be basically anything (mind the `List<Any>` type) and thus the compiler has no way to tell you that the types are not compatible. You will have the same issue with the following code (a changed version of your first example):

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var num2 = 100000
    val numList: List<Int> = listOf(num2)

    for(num in numList) {
        if (num is Short) {
            println("Short: $num")
        } else if (num is Int) {
            println("Int: $num")
        } else if (num is Long) {
            println("Long: $num")
        } else {
            println("$num not in listed types")
        }
    }
}
```